# Regular expression to find file name using any Javascript based library

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, node.js, lodash

I am working with markdown editor. After user uploads an image I see following line being entered on the editor.

```
![](/assets/img/content/id/2e65c657cf609fca24893278cdcb2159.gif)
```

**What I want is:** I want to extract the file name by searching content of entire editor.

assume I have following content on my editor:

```
Hello world.pdf
![](/assets/img/content/id/2e65c657cf609fca24893278cdcb2159.gif)
This is a test

![](/assets/img/content/id/2e65c657cf609fcaeqwe78cdcb2159.png)adding text

Adding another image

![](/assets/img/content/id/2e65c657cf609f24432434423b2159.jpg)
```

From the above content, after running the regular expression, I should be able to get:

```
2e65c657cf609fca24893278cdcb2159.gif
2e65c657cf609fcaeqwe78cdcb2159.png
2e65c657cf609f24432434423b2159.jpg
```

**I have tried something like this. Though its working, I am not sure its the best solution:**

```
var myregex = /\(\/assets\/img\/content\/id\/(.+?)\)/gm

var result, allMatches = [];
while((result = myregex.exec(data)) != null) {
    var match = result[1]; // get the first match pattern of this match
    allMatches.push(match);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you need a library to do this?

Comment: @nnnnnn: I just wanted to know if there is any library which can do the trick for me. I have updated my question to include my solution as well.

Comment: any reason for downvote ?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but perhaps whoever did thought you should've shown what you'd already tried. (Which obviously you have now added.)

Answer (score 3):

Use following `regex`:

```
var fileNames = content.match(/(\w+\.[a-z]{3,4})/gi);
```

**REGEX Explanation**

1. `/`: Delimiters of `regex`
2. `()`: Capturing Group
3. `\w+`: Matches one or more of any alphabetical character and `_`(underscore)
4. `\.`: Matches `.` literal
5. `[a-z]{3,4}`: Matches 3 to 4 alphabets
6. `gi`: Match all occurrences `g` and case insensitive `i`

[**DEMO**](http://www.regexr.com/3b8u6)

[**JsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/hnsgkurb/2/)

**UPDATE**

```
var fileNames = content.match(/\!\[\].*?(\w+\.[a-z]{3,4})/gi);

fileNames = fileNames.toString();

var names = fileNames.match(/\w+\.[a-z]{3,4}/gi);
alert(names);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/hnsgkurb/3/)

Comment: Are you sure of `[gif|png|jpg|jpeg]*`? It only matches 0 or more symbols that are either `g` or `i`, or `j` or `n` or `p`, or `g`, or `e`, or `|`. In character classes, `|` is not a separator, it is a literal pipe symbol.

Comment: @stribizhev You're right! Please check updated answer

Comment: @Tushar: I can have any type of files. I cannot confirm if the file type will be only image.

Comment: @Tushar: Your solution is partly working. If I add `Hello world.pdf` in my document, this regular expression would return `Hello world.pdf` as well..

Comment: @SharpCoder you stated above that "I cannot confirm if the file type will be only image". that's why Tushar made the amendments

Comment: @garyh: Thank you for quick reply. I am getting input from markdown editor & user is allowed to enter any data. assuming user enters a string like `hello.pdf`, the current expression also adds this as a valid file. But I think the expression should only consider those file which has following pattern:  `![](/assets/img/content/id/`  follwed by `file name`

Comment: @Tushar the update will also match other paths eg `/assets/doc/content/id/`

Comment: @garyh I've answered according to the question, let OP decide if he want to use this or not

Comment: @Tushar the OP stated in the comment "the expression should only consider those file which has following pattern: `![](/assets/img/content/id/` follwed by `file name`"

Comment: @garyh DID you check the updated answer and **DEMO**?

Comment: @Tushar Yes, That's why I made the comment

Answer (score 0):

Try this (for images)

`/(\w+\.(?:gif|png|jpe?g))/gi`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/mH6mG0/1)

or for any file type

`/(\w+\.(?:\w{2,4}))/gi`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/mH6mG0/2)

**UPDATE**

Based on comments made on @Tushar's answer

`(?:\/assets\/img\/content\/id\/)(\w+\.(?:\w{2,4}))`

will find any file with the preceding path `/assets/img/content/id/`. As one of the tags stated `javascript` we cannot use a [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/mH6mG0/3)